# Properly calling a parameterized std::function

Tags: c++, std-function

I'm new to `std::function` and have been using it for trivial tasks. One of my projects passes an `std::string` into an `std::function()`– but now I would like to pass a `rapidjson::Document` instead.

Why does an `std::string` seamlessly work and `rapidjson::Document` does not? Is it because the document object is allocated on the stack and not the heap? Should I wrap this in a smart pointer?

I am struggling to understand the error itself and am hoping someone could explain what it means: `call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion function to pointer-to-function type`

Here is my existing code:

```
std::function<void(const std::string&)> callback_;

...

bool set_callback(std::function<void(const std::string&)>&& callback) {
    callback_ = callback;
}

void some_event() {
    std::string serialize = serializer.to_string(an_object);

    callback_(data);
}

...

// The callback event
void the_callback(const std::string& data) {
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
}
```

The callback will now take an object document and the serialization will be done in another class entirely. So I would like my `std::function` to reflect this:

```
std::function<void(rapidjson::Document&)> callback_;

...

void some_event() {
    rapidjson::Document document = serializer.get_document();

    // This is where the error occurs
    callback_(document);
}
```

Comment: If you're going to provide an error, you need to provide the line that the error is produced from.

Comment: Code fragments like this are not enough to diagnose your problem -- they look fine in isolation, and likely work fine with the appropriate other code to make them work.  You need to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the RapidJSON documentation](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_faq.html), its `Document` and `Value` types are invariants that provide move-semantic operations but not copy-semantics:

> - Q. What is move semantics? Why?
> - A. Instead of copy semantics, move semantics is used in Value. That
>     means, when assigning a source value to a target value, the ownership
>     of source value is moved to the target value.
>
>   Since moving is faster than copying, this design decision forces user
>     to aware of the copying overhead.

Since you didn’t list the rest of the code changes you made when refitting this example to pass `rapidjson::Document&` references instead of `std::string const&` references, you should double-check that your `set_callback(…)` function is in sync with this change (and if possible, update your post to reflect this) and ensure that your functional signatures are move-semantic friendly (e.g. capable of receiving `rapidjson::Document&&` rvalue references).

Also, as Nichol Bolas mentioned above, the error message you posted could use some context (at which line did it occur; which compiler was in use, &c).

Comment: I have updated the `set_callback()` to reflect these changes. I was using a `typedef` in my original code but decided against it in my post for better clarity. But I will update OP to better reflect what I have on paper.

Comment: Looks like the issue was directly related to my `typedef`. Not sure why but doing a `typedef std::function<void(const rapidjson::Document&)> f_callback` does not work.

Comment: @user0000001 I would think that you are confusing the use of `std::function<…>` with how one `typedef`s a callable: you probably wanted to just do `typedef std::add_pointer_t<void(rapidjson::Document const&)> f_callback` -- note how the signature of a function in this case contributes to its typological identity. Doing this is a more legible way than `typedef`ing a function pointer in the idiomatic C-language style.

Comment: user0000001 … the takeaway here is: you do not need to specialize `std::function<…>` in order to specify the signature of a callable type.